# submit form in jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui, dynamic, submit

i have several form that their name are different, my php code create these forms.

so i created a dynamic javascript that take form id and submit this.
but submit doesn`t work and it haven`t any error!!!

my javascript code:

```
 $( ".create_form" )
            .click(function() {
                var b = $(this).attr('id');
                $tempId = ("#dialog-form" + b);
                $tempName = ("#NemberForm" + b);
                //==========
                 $( $tempId ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 200,
                    width: 350,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "accept": function() {

                                $($tempName).submit(function() {
                                return true;
                            })
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );   
                        }
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
         })
                $( $tempId ).dialog( "open" );
            });

        });
```

my form code:

```
 <form method="post" id="NemberForm1" action="index.php?file=trade&operation=accept&id=1&flag=true">

                            <label for="name">number of trade</label>
                            <input type="text" name="number" id="number" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

                        </form>
```

Comment: There does not seem to be any html element with the class "create_form", this may be the reason for the event not firing.  if this is a button, maybe include more information.

Comment: i have that but i dn`t put there.

Comment: Are you 100% sure this event is being called?

Comment: yes, it show me a light box that there is a textbox and a button but after select button loghtbox`s closing but form dosent submit !!

Comment: Did any of these answers help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: $($tempName).submit();

Comment: i tested this but no thing has changed !

Comment: So, replace: $($tempName).submit(function() {
                                return true;
                            }) by $($tempName).submit(); It works for me. Your code never submit the form, your code say "when the form will be submitted return true" not "submit the form".

Comment: i changed that but no thing happend :(

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There looks like you have an error in your javascript:

```
Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
     })// <---- this should not be here
            $( $tempId ).dialog( "open" );
```